# Nested dict in Django model

Tags: python, django

I have Django project and I need to create model with fields, which every of them must have 17 fields of string, something like nested dict.

Code below doesnt work, just example. I need something like that:

```
class LimitValues(models.Model):
    stateDescription = models.TextField() # x17


class VSRGraduation(models.Model):
    some_field_1= models.ForeignKey(LimitValues)
    some_field_2= models.ForeignKey(LimitValues)
    some_field_3= models.ForeignKey(LimitValues)
    # etc... total 15 some_fields
```

Maybe you are faced with same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to represent it using `1 to Many` relationships.

`1 VSRGraduation` instance can be pointed by `Many LimitValues` instances

`1 LimitValues` instance can be pointed by `Many LimitValuesState` instances

```
class LimitValuesState(models.Model):
   stateDescription = models.TextField()
   limitvalue = models.ForeignKey(LimitValues)

class LimitValues(models.Model):
    vsr_graduation = models.ForeignKey(VSRGraduation)


class VSRGraduation(models.Model):
     #extra model fields
```